# Get builds in a Perforce changelist from Jenkins

Tags: plugins, build, jenkins, perforce, changelist

I am working on a jenkins plugin that consists in displaying information on a new page on Jenkins.
The information I need to display is the changelists from Perforce.
This, I manage to do with the command

```
"p4 changelists"
```

What I don't know how to do is get all the builds that are inside the changelists, to be able to tell if a given changelist is successful or unsuccessful.
Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by get all the builds inside the changelist? You mean all the builds related to the changelist?

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the changelist from the perforce plugin env var
you can run the following shell
echo p4.changelist=$P4_CHANGELIST > change.properties
cf. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Perforce+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet [supported](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7436) by Jenkins however you can write simple parametrized build and unshelve given CL before build is up and running. [This article](http://www.jroller.com/francoisledroff/entry/perforce_shelving_jenkins) may be helpful.